# Setting up XlsxReaderWriter - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, github

I'm trying to use the XlsxReaderWriter library from Github - https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter

I have followed the steps and now this is my project hierarchy - http://postimg.org/image/4daa89bo7/

I have added the project as a sub project and added it in the target dependencies and added the libXlsxReaderWriter.a to the binary like this - http://postimg.org/image/3l2z7uxyl/

The problem is that I can't use the library and that the libXlsxReaderWriter library is marked in red.

How can I set up the XlsxReaderWriter library correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just committed some code plus a Swift bridge header file. You should use it as your bridge header file or #import it from your current one.

Let me know if everything run fine. I'm still using Obj-C (shame on me!), so I've never tested it with Swift.

Cheers

Comment: I added the bridging header but I get ab error saying i'm trying to import a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: I can get rid of this error, but I'm getting another one with an NSDictionary category method that can't be called from Swift. I don't know why. Need some time to figure that.

Comment: I've successfully managed to compile Swift code with the library. Pull the repo from Github and read the README.MD file.

Comment: I didn't understand what path should I write in the user header search paths

Comment: Just in case someone is wondering: The project README.md describes how to use the library with Swift.